# opencart one page checkout error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, shopping-cart, opencart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

I have opencart framework and shoppica template. Recently I have installed "one page checkout" module that supportes shoppica but when I enable this module i get the following error:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: lang in public_html/catalog/view/theme/default/template/onecheckout/checkout.tpl on line 3
```

checkout.tpl line 3:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="<?php echo $direction; ?>" lang="<?php echo $lang; ?>" xml:lang="<?php echo $lang; ?>">
```

My opencart version is 1.5.3.1 
shoppica v2.2
one page checkout 3.4
Please help me.

Comment: Define `$lang` before using it.

Comment: Do you have something like: `$this->data['lang'] = 'some value, you need';` in your controller? In another words, if you don't define variable it will be undefined.

Comment: @PLB yes I have $this->data['lang'] = $this->language->get('code'); in header.php in controller.